# what's the proper way to terminate all threads spawned by a Visual Studio Addin?

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, add-in

When the addin is unloaded and the OnDisconnection() method runs, I want all thredas spawned by the addin to be terminated immediately. More specifically, if one of those threads or the main thread created, say, a MessageBox, I want the message box to be destroyed the moment the add-in is unloaded.

The behavior I'm seeing right now is that when I unload the addin (Tools -> Manage Add-in) threads keep running in the background and addin-related UI stays in plain sight until the user manually closes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost,

> I want all thredas spawned by the addin to be terminated immediately.

**No, you don't.** What you want is the other threads to stop running themselves in a normal manner. Asynchronous exceptions (such as `ThreadAbortException`) are likely to leave the application in a bad state, which is the complete opposite of what you're trying to accomplish.

Without knowing the specific reason why your add-in has multiple threads, I can only make the following suggestions:

- Make sure long-running operations can be cancelled by setting a flag in your add-in or calling some sort of cancellation callback.
- Avoid keeping idle threads running (when the work is done, the thread's main function should return and the thread will stop running).
- If you can't stop the add-in, you can notify the user that changes will be applied the next time Visual Studio is restarted. The [`IVsUIShell.ShowMessageBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsuishell.showmessagebox.aspx) method is probably what you want to use for this notification.
- I have not used it before, but it appears the [`IVsThreadedWaitDialogFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsthreadedwaitdialogfactory.aspx) provided by the Visual Studio shell was created for addressing some issues in this space.

Answer (score 1):

Some helpful resources:
[C#, visual studio 2010, how to stop a method, threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025496/c-visual-studio-2010-how-to-stop-a-method-threads)

[How To: Create and Terminate Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

As listed in the first link, it is advised to look into [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)